# Fastest way to find maximum value of a function in each interval in R

Tags: performance, r

I have a vector, `v`, and a vector of intervals, `w`. I want to find the maximum value of a function, `f(x)`, in each interval. Is there a faster way than following code for finding the result? For example:

```
v = c(3.5, 2.5, 4, 6.5, 10, 2.3, 1.8, 4.7, 12, 11.5)
w = c(0, 5, 15, 20)
f = function(x){x^2}
> max = unlist(list(sapply(split(v, cut(v, w),drop = TRUE),
               function(v) v[which.max(f(v))])), use.names = FALSE)
> max
[1]  4.7 12.0
```

Comment: Are you not concerned that `w` defines three sets (one is empty), yet your output is a vector of length `2`? Rather, would you consider a list of length `3` as your output?

Comment: No, I just need the result without intervals with numeric().

Comment: Seems optimzed for me, but you could remove `unlist(list(` and replace `sapply` with `vapply`. One thing to note is that `f` is being called once for every interval you have. This could be a bottleneck if the intervals get more numerous (and smaller), depending on how `f` is coded.

Comment: I remove them but I got this error:> max = vapply(split(v, cut(v, w)),function(v) v[which.max(f(v))])
Error in vapply(split(v, cut(v, w)), function(v) v[which.max(f(v))]) : 
  argument "FUN.VALUE" is missing, with no default

Comment: @rose, you can add the argument `FUN.VALUE=numeric(1)` to indicate that your function returns a numeric vector of length 1. Just put it after the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `findInterval` and `tapply`. `findInterval` is like `cut`, but without the overhead of converting to factors

```
tapply(v,findInterval(v,w),function(x)x[which.max(f(x))])
#   1    2 
#  4.7 12.0
```

Or if you want the maximum value

```
tapply(f(v),findInterval(v,w),max)
#    1      2 
# 22.09 144.00
```

Or you could use the fact that your function is monotonically increasing for all positive values and do.

```
f(tapply(v,findInterval(v,w),max))
```

Note that you will need to specify what happens at the boundaries (read the help file)

```
library(microbenchmark)
     microbenchmark(
        mnel = tapply(v,findInterval(v,w),max),
        flodel = unname(vapply(split(f(v), cut(v, w), drop = TRUE), max, numeric(1L))),
        flodel2 = unname(vapply(split(seq_along(v), findInterval(v, w)), function(i, v, fv)v[i][which.max(fv[i])], numeric(1L), v, f(v))))
#  Unit: microseconds
#   expr     min       lq   median       uq     max neval
#   mnel 260.945 262.9155 264.2265 276.0645 458.670   100
# flodel 331.218 334.3585 336.0580 351.1985 694.715   100
#flodel2 124.998 127.3230 128.5170 137.0505 354.545   100
```

Comment: How can I remove header form the result?

Comment: My desire result is the value of v which has maximum value of f(x) in each interval not the value of f(x).> max
[1]  4.7 12.0

Comment: @rose - you are confused about what you want. You function is monotonically increasing for all positive values, so the maximum value for v within an interval will give the maximum value of f(v). I've given you code to do both. Use which ever you need.

Comment: Try `unname(vapply(split(seq_along(v), findInterval(v, w)), function(i, v, fv)v[i][which.max(fv[i])], numeric(1L), v, f(v)))`